# ML accuracy for a particular group/range

Tags: machine-learning

General terms that I used to search on google such as Localised Accuracy, custom accuracy, biased cost functions all seem wrong, and maybe I am not even asking the right questions.

Imagine I have some data, may it be the:

1. The famous Iris Classification Problem
2. Pictures of felines
3. The Following Dataset that I made up on predicting house prices:

[image]

In all these scenario, I am really interested in the accuracy of one set/one regression range of data.

1. For irises, I really need Iris "setosa" to be classified correctly, really don't care if Iris virginica and Iris versicolor are all wrong.
2. for Felines, I really need the model to tell me if you spotted a tiger (for obvious reason), whether it is a Persian or ragdoll or not I dont really care.
3. For the house prices one, i want the accuracy of higher-end houses error to be minimised. Because error in those is costly.

How do I do this? If I want Setosa to be classified correctly, removing virginica or versicolour both seem wrong. Trying different algorithm like Linear/SVM etc are all well and good, but it only improves the OVERALL accuracy. But I really need, for example, "Tigers" to be predicted correctly, even at the expense of the "overall" accuracy of the model.

Is there a way to have a custom cost-function to allow me to have a high accuracy in a localise region in a regression problem, or a specific category in a classification problem?

If this cannot be answered, if you could just point me to some terms that i can search/research that would still be greatly appreciated.

Comment: one of the solutions is to use neural network and add custom loss functions which will give large penalty score to the model once it predicts wrong setosa.

Comment: see [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-custom-loss-function-keras-3a89156ec69b)

Comment: Hi Prakash, thanks for this, certainly worth looking at, this is an awesome community. I wonder if this would also work for regression, it seems that it will work. Stay safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use weights to achieve that. If you're using the [SVC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn-svm-svc) class of scikit-learn, you can pass `class_weight` in the constructor. You could also pass `sample_weight` in the fit-method.

For example:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

clf = svm.SVC(class_weight={0: 3, 1: 1, 2: 1})
clf.fit(X, y)
```

This way setosa is more important than the other classes.

Example for regression

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = ... # features
y = ... # house prices
weights = []
for house_price in y:
  if house_price > threshold:
     weights.append(3)
  else:
     weights.append(1)

clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X, y, sample_weight=weights)
```

Comment: Hi hnfl, thanks for the tip, i am going to give it a try for categorical case. For Regression, let me know if you have any direction. I am also going to follow Prakash Dahal's recommendation of a custom loss function with a neural network too!

Comment: For regression you can use `sample_weight` in the fit call or resample data manually.